# Embedding a JSF page on a PHP application (magento)

Tags: php, magento, jsf

I have an advanced product selector that was made using JSF (primefaces), it runs on a dedicated server and its part of a bigger aplication. I also have a webstore that runs PHP + Magento on other server where I want to embedded this product selector. Is it possible or I'll need to implement a new PHP product selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue using iframe html element. It worked well with primefaces + ajax requests.

Answer (score 0):

Magento needs to know about your products. This means you need a way to feed your products into magento. IMHO the cleanest way is to provide the products via a web service. Once you have this, you have two options

1. Look for a way to "steal" the "add to cart" event from the existing selector on the browser (JavaScript) and call an "add to cart" URL on the magento side.
2. Once you have the products in magento you have everything you have to write your own selector based on magento/PHP.

Comment: Dear BetaRide, the selector has as final output the product list with hyperlinks to product page (I can extract it direcly from magento database). What I want to know is if a JSF frame on Magento will render/behaves correctly, I don´t know if the requests/css/scripts will be correcly handled by the jsf container/magento